# Strange behavior of celery workers in ecs docker container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, celery, amazon-ecs

We have a number of `c4.large` ecs instances, each of those has one running docker container with running celery workers. From time to time we see that workers are killed by system

```
WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)
```

In `dmesg` I can see following line:

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 27886 (celery) score 112 or sacrifice child
```

As I understand OOM is responsible for this

But I also can see this line in `dmesg`:

```
memory: usage 964544kB, limit 1048576kB, failcnt 246284
```

Which says that there is a limit in 1 GB, but I don't understand what is the reason for this limit, since `free -m` says

```
             total      used      free    shared   buffers    cached
Mem:          3768      3461       307         0       140      2211
-/+ buffers/cache:      1108      2659
Swap:            0         0         0
```

The other important point is that we have an ordinary ec2 `c4.large` instance, where we have celery running with the same number of workers (or even more), but without docker, and we never saw this problem on this instance. So I guess it could be some docker overhead which consumes memory, but maybe I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`free` shows total amount of memory [regardless of cgroup limits](http://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/) and memory available to container so you are seeing confusing numbers.

cgroup limit can be specified for docker container via command line or in case of amazon via task definition. Check `memory` [parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions).